# Save each log in a separate line in Golang

Tags: logging, go

I tried to add log for my code but i couldn't get each log on a separate line

This is my code

```
  package main

 import (
         "log"
         "os"
 )

func update(){
    log.Println(1,"update")
    log.Println(1,"update")
    log.Println(1,"update")
    log.Println(1,"update")
}
func install(){

    log.Println(1,"install")
    log.Println(1,"install")
    log.Println(1,"install")
    log.Println(1,"install")


}
 func main() {

         // make sure log.txt exists first
         // use touch command to create if log.txt does not exist
         os.Create("log/Installationlog.txt")
         logFile, err := os.OpenFile("log/Installationlog.txt", os.O_WRONLY, 0666)

         if err != nil {
                 panic(err)
         }

         defer logFile.Close()

         // direct all log messages to log.txt
         log.SetOutput(logFile)

         log.Println("ERROR::First log message!")
         install()
         update()
 }
```

The output of my code is

```
2016/01/18 13:30:51 ERROR::First log message! 2016/01/18 13:30:51 1 install 2016/01/18 13:30:51 1 install 2016/01/18 13:30:51 1 install 2016/01/18 13:30:51 1 install 2016/01/18 13:30:51 1 update 2016/01/18 13:30:51 1 update 2016/01/18 13:30:51 1 update 2016/01/18 13:30:51 1 update
```

All in a single line i want each of them to be in separate line

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your code prints the log file properly on my machine. Perhaps you're viewing it on Windows and it's a matter of \n vs \r\n?

Comment: `log.Println()` appends a newline (which is OS dependent). Most likely on the OS you run it is just the `'\n'` and your console or text viewer doesn't start a new line (e.g. Windows Notepad only starts newline if `"\r\n"` is the terminator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe This code will help u ("\n" -> "\n\r")*("\n\r" works same as "\r\n")*:

```
log.SetPrefix("\r")
```